# Why does Visual Studio Code's intellisense break in this simple Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I found that VSCode's intellisense breaks when a Javascript object contains assignment to another property of the same object. Example:

```
var obj = {
    a: 0,
    b: "",

    func1: function () {
        // do something
    },

    func2: function() {
        this.func1();
        console.log(this.a + this.b);
        //this.a = 1;
    }
}
```

When typed into VSCode, everything works well - syntax is highlighted correctly and intellisense recognizes all items. Mousing over terms gives their explanation, code completion gives correct predictions, etc.

But uncommenting the line `this.a = 1` in the definition of `func2` breaks this. The name of `func2` changes color to green (functions are normally yellow), mousing over `func2` it tells us it is `typeof func2`, and `this`, `func1`, `a`, and `b` within `func2` are not recognized either.

However, running this code does not produce any errors - the line `this.a = 1` correctly changes the property `a` of `obj`, and everything works as expected.

So why does VSCode do this, and is there a way to fix it?

**Edit:** Using `//@ts-check` leads to similar errors - without `this.a = 1`, everything is alright, but with it, the same errors appear. It's as if @ts-check stopped seeing `func2` as a member of `obj`.

Comment: I would suggest that you report  a bug at the relevant GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

I am far from a VSCode expert, but I've had the syntax recognition break on me both on VSCode and WebStorm before, and restarting the program, resetting your settings, may or may not work. These things can be buggy in certain use cases. Mine for example was checking out different git branches in my npm project and suddenly all of the imports broke for no reason. Not the most scientific answer, but best of luck

Comment: Thanks, but it does not help. I also tried it on a different computer, with the same results. So perhaps the issue is not at my end.